# Find vectors $u$ and $v$ such that the parametrization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find vectors $u$ and $v$ such that the parametrization $w(t) = u + tv$ describes the line containing the points $(5,2)$ and $(-1,3)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think, you might put the points into the equation and then solve the resulted system of equations to find the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

(For clarity reasons I'll be using column vector notation) Consider the vectors as
$$u = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2\end{pmatrix}, v = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now, since the line that defines the union of the points $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1-5 \\ 3-2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},$$
we can conclude that your vector $u$ will determine the "position" of your line, and $v$ will determine the "direction" (this is because the vector with the parameter in $w$'s formula is $v$), so we can conclude that $u_1=5,u_2=2,v_1=-6,v_2=1$, to be said:
$$w(t)= u+tv=\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 5-6t \\ 2+t\end{pmatrix}$$